# Questions answered before being posted: what happened?

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm playing with stackoverflow's data dump and found something unexpected.

After writing all questions (among with their answers) tagged with Java into mongodb, I did a little sanity check and found out there were 45 questions without enough answers, i.e., the answer count written into the database is less than the real count.

So I went to some of the question pages and found that obviously some answers were written before the questions were posted. My code had an underlying assumption that questions came first. Thus the problem.

Take [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462923/java-embedded-databases-comparison?answertab=active#tab-top) as an example, the question was asked on **Jan 20 '09 at 20:17** but there were several answers (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58691/1062364)) written on **Sep 12 '08**.

The thing is according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow),

> On **15 September 2008** it was announced the public beta version was in session and that the general public was now able to use it to seek assistance on programming related issues.

So these answers were probably not written on **Sep 12 '08**.

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389561/referential-integrity-with-one-to-one-using-hibernate). It's the latest one with the problem. The question was asked on Mar 22 '11 but one answered was posted on Mar.18 '11.

There must have been a bug (that probably has been fixed), but what bug? And... the real answer dates can't be recovered anymore?

**EDIT:** Thanks everyone. My reasoning has failed. There is no bug. It was just questions getting merged...

**But... Now... Why not use the earlier date of the two in the end?**

Comment: Off the top of my head, it could be the result of a merge of two questions.

Comment: Indeed, it's the result of a merge.

Comment: If you look at the edit history of any of the answers that appear older than they should, you'll see something like: `Post Merged (destination) from stackoverflow.com/questions/57102/embedded-java-databases`

Comment: Also, there were 2k+ users here before the *public beta* -- so why do you thing those dates don't work?

Comment: @TZHX my reasoning has failed :( miserably

Comment: @TZHX but it's a bit strange seeing that though.

Comment: @TZHX And ... why don't they use the older date of the merged questions in the end. I think that would make more sense.

Comment: I assume someone (well, George Stocker) thought the newer question was better worded, or had a better accepted answer (which is something the mods can't change), you can still see the text of the older question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/57102/519348). I don't know if there's a way to see which answer on the old question was accepted (or if any was)

Comment: @TZHX: Yes, see the timeline: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/462923/timeline Chris Dail's answer was accepted pre-merge: http://stackoverflow.com/a/57352